# Quartz Cron Trigger, runs twice

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have cron expression

```
0 0/45 * * * ?
```

Which happens to run twice, e.g. first run is 8:45 AM next run is 9:00 AM, 9:45 AM, ..10:00 AM

Is something wrong?

Comment: What did you expect it to do, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cron expression says that it should run at the top of the hour (0) or 45 minutes past the hour (45).  This is the expected behavior.

Comment: Are you looking to trigger every hour?  Still not sure what the problem is.